# updater-script for flashing raw partition image

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, zip

I created the image with the following commands

```
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p1 of=/mnt/sdcard/modem.img
dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p5 of=/mnt/sdcard/aboot.img
```

Now, I want to create a flashable zip to flash these images to another copy of the device.

1. Do I need to format the partition before I write the raw image in the first place?
2. Is this script okay if I assume no formatting is needed?

   ```
   ui_print("Updating modem.img ...");
   write_raw_image("aboot.img", "/dev/block/mmcblk0p5");
   write_raw_image("modem.img", "/dev/block/mmcblk0p1");
   ui_print("Finished!");
   ui_print();
   ```

   If it needs formating, I use the Partition Table app to identify the partitions.
   It shows for `/dev/block/mmcblk0p1` mount point and filesystem type ("vfat") but for `/dev/block/mmcblk0p5` this info is absent.
3. How do I know the filesystem type "EMMC" or "MTD" or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `write_raw_image` works only from the filesystem and does what `dd`` does. The proper way would be to just extract the images:

```
package_extract_file("aboot.img", "/dev/block/mmcblk0p5");
package_extract_file("modem.img", "/dev/block/mmcblk0p1");
```